# Force UITextView into emoji only mode

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview

I have a UITextView and I want to force the keyboard into an Emoji only state. I would like the user to only have the option to be on the emoji keyboard. I don't want something where the user can  click on ASCII characters but they won't do anything.

I have this code here and for the most part it works. It doesn't allow you to leave the emoji keyboard when you click the "ABC" on the bottom left. However, things start to get funky when you try searching for an emoji. The keyboard gets into a weird state and then jumps out of emoji mode.

```
final class ExampleInputTextView: UITextView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero, textContainer: nil)
        keyboardType = .default
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(inputModeDidChange),
                                               name: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }

    @objc func inputModeDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard isFirstResponder else {
            return
        }
        self.reloadInputViews()
        }
    }

    override var textInputContextIdentifier: String? { "emoji" }

    override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
        for mode in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
            if mode.primaryLanguage == "emoji" {
                return mode
            }
        }
        return super.textInputMode
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can have the ability to still search for emojis but otherwise be forced in the emoji state.

Comment: Another way to do this would be through `UITextViewDelegate` and '`textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` and preventing non-emoji text being accepted.

Comment: Yes that is a valid solution; however, I almost want the keyboard to act as an emoji picker, and only show emojis

Comment: Sounds like you need to a custom `inputView` for the textView that acts as an emoji picker (unless you can assign the system one as a keyboard??)

Comment: Yeah.. which is a lot of work haha

Comment: what do you mean by "unless you can assign the system on as a keyboard" isn't that what im trying to do in this question

Comment: Yep, it'll involve work.  I meant assign it as a discrete keyboard (rather than linked to the standard one, with the problems that's creating).  I can't think of a way to do this,  but I've not tried either.

Comment: do you mind giving me some more information or documentation about discrete keyboards?

Comment: @driverDran - if you head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift emoji picker` you'll find many examples, discussions, articles, etc. Probably something already out there that you could use directly. If nothing fits your exact needs, you would at least be able to find something to modify / build on.

Comment: yeah, at least for localization the default keyboard is best. I presume they use searching of emojis based off a few keywords in the third party ones and all in english. it would be a massive effort to translate everything

Comment: @driverDran by discrete keyboards I was (badly!) referring to the various `UIKeyboardType` options.   Not that they are going to help you here.

Comment: yeah.. i wish there was an emoji one